# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory: ConvNet.py\\1

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow-serving

I want to save my convolutional neural model, but i've got this error

```
   Exporting trained model to b'ConvNet.py\\1'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "ConvNet.py", line 285, in <module>
        builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\builder_impl.py", line 90, in __init__
        file_io.recursive_create_dir(self._export_dir)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 367, in recursive_create_dir
        pywrap_tensorflow.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.as_bytes(dirname), status)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 88, in __exit__
        next(self.gen)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
        pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory: ConvNet.py\\1
```

Here is the part of the code that I'm using

```
export_path_base = sys.argv[-1]
export_path = os.path.join(
  compat.as_bytes(export_path_base),
  compat.as_bytes(str(1)))
print ('Exporting trained model to', export_path)

builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(export_path)

classification_inputs = utils.build_tensor_info(serialized_tf_example)
classification_outputs_classes = utils.build_tensor_info(prediction_classes)
classification_outputs_scores = utils.build_tensor_info(values)
```